# 25% probability that there was a chance of avoiding injury $\quad$ vs. $\quad$ 25% chance of avoiding injury

Tags: probability

I ask about merely the math behind the last sentence of footnote 71 quoted below. I quote the legalistic sentences thereinbefore for context, but they may be immaterial.

##### How does "a 25% probability that there was a chance of avoiding injury" differ from "25% chance of avoiding injury"? Alas, my mind is conflating these 2 chances.

> 71 Though some academics do insist that damages for loss of a chance could have been awarded in *Hotson* [*v East Berkshire Health Authority*
> [1987] AC 750 268]:
> see Peel 2003b, 627, and references contained therein. An amazing number of academics argue that the
> fact that the House of Lords awarded the claimant in *Hotson* nothing means that *Hotson* is authority for
> the proposition that damages for loss of a chance of avoiding physical injury cannot be claimed in
> negligence: see Porat & Stein 2003, 679; Weir 2004, 214–15. As the majority of the Court of Appeal
> recognised in *Gregg v Scott* [2002] EWCA Civ 1471 (at [39], per Latham LJ and at [78], per Mance LJ)
> this is incorrect – the facts of the case in Hotson were such that the claimant simply could not bring a
> claim for loss of a chance against the defendants. See, to the same effect, Reece 1996; also Hill 1991.
> Fleming 1997 puts the point quite well (at 69): **‘[A] 25% probability that there was a chance [of avoiding
> injury cannot] be conflated into a 25% chance [of avoiding injury].’**

N.J. McBride and R. Bagshaw, *Tort Law*, 6th edn (2018), page 280, footnote 71.

In the last sentence, "Fleming 1997" refers to John G. Fleming, “Preventive Damages” in N J Mullany (ed), *Torts in the Nineties* (LBC Information Services, Sydney, 1997), pp 56-71.

Comment: Suppose I flip a coin three times and don’t want to get tails at all. Then 75% of the time, I will have failed after the second flip. In the remaining 25% of cases, there is still a chance that I can avoid tails. (That said, this framing seems needlessly complicated to me: it’s just the difference between “the probability of success is at most 25%” and “the probability equals 25%”.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is a $25\%$ chance that there is a *possibility* of avoiding injury. While the second is a $25\%$ chance of avoiding injury. For example If I go up to a barrel of four snakes and one of the snakes is non-venomous, I have a one in four chance of picking up a snake without getting a venomous bite. i.e. a one in four chance of avoiding injury.

But say there were three other barrels, and they all had *only* venomous snakes. When I went up to these barrels I had a one in four chance of going up to the barrel with the one non-venomous snake. That is a $25\%$ chance of the possibility of avoiding injury.

Disclaimer: I do suggest simply walking away from the barrels.